# Python ValueError: cannot rehape array: works at Mac but error at Windows

Tags: python, numpy, selenium, python-imaging-library, openai-gym

I am trying to make an AI bot that automatically learns to play GeometryDash. However,
I keep getting this error:

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 685440 into shape (689,1024,1)
```

*If I run this using Mac, it runs without any problem.

*Resizing image does not not show error but does not run as intended

*Fixing window size did not work

My code:

```
def __init__(self):
    super(GeometryDash, self).__init__()

    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('window-size=1024,768')
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),
        options=options
        )
    self._init_browser()

    self.action_space = spaces.Discrete(2) # Jump, No action
    self.observation_space = spaces.Box(
        low=0, 
        high=255, 
        shape=(689, 1024, 1),
        dtype=np.uint8
        ) #Images

@property
def observation(self) -> np.array:
    img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(self.driver.get_screenshot_as_png())).convert('L')
    return np.array(img).reshape(self.observation_space.shape)
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: 689*1024 is 705536

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @hpaulj. The array size of `685440` does not match the shape size of 689, 1024. As `689*1024` is not `685440`.

You would need to find out why `img` does have the expected size or adjust `shape=(689, 1024, 1)`. For example `shape=(640, 1071, 1)` would not cause an error but might be visually not correct.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Do you have any clue why it might work in Mac but not in Windows with the same code, Chrome version, Selenium version, and etc?

Comment: Sorry, I can only guess. Is your screen resolution different on the two operating systems?